# phonegap.js (cordova.js) functionality missing, or invalid

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

Ok, trying to build out my first phonegap based project and I am coming to a point where I need to start tieing into the device such as the camera. Which I can't do due to errors like:

```
Can't find variable: FileUploadOptions
```

Which I have found means that I have to have this js file called phonegap.js. Which from what I have learned generates at the time of building out your app. However. Sometime in the recent past support for phonegap.js has been removed, and cordova.js is now apparently the file that replaces it. Which this did generate. However the function above for example, fails because there is no reference to such a function/class anywhere in cordova.js yet the cordova docs/help point to phonegap docs.. which tell you to include this plugin (which I do) and tells me how to do things which I follow to a letter so I can first try to get it working. So, this continues to fail.

I go out and find a copy of a phonegap.js but its useless to me as its an older version concept. 1.9.0 (and who knows which platform it was generated for) Either way for giggles I try with that one I get a syntax error. Soooo..

Can someone for the sake of my sanity tell me, one, why is it so hard for the docs to describe these things. two.. If the file is supposed to generate, but doesn't yet its required, what does one do?

Comment: Are you using Dreamweaver or any IDE?

Comment: I use Coda for my general edits of the HTML JS I use/add into the WWW folder.. But Xcode remains open for any needed edits otherwise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cordova.js is missing on a new project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19247356/cordova-js-is-missing-on-a-new-project)

Comment: lol @Xenocideae, or maybe the one you link to is a duplicate of this one, seeing as that one was asked a month after this one if you look at the dates, not to mention almost 9 months ago as well..

Comment: lol @chris, yeah, just wanted the link for future reference and future visitors. This small issue has caused many big headaches for me before so trying to make it as easy to find as possible. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a long time since you asked your question so I will answer for PhoneGap version 3.3.

You need to build your project for iOS with `phonegap local build ios`. Then the phonegap.js file will in `$PROJECT_ROOT/platforms/ios/www` directory.

Make sure you include `phonegap.js` in your `index.html` file, near the bottom so that it is after any dependencies.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

You may see warnings that cordova.js is not found, but this is ok as long as you have phonegap.js.

For reference, Apache Cordova is an open source project and PhoneGap offers some extra features on top of Cordova.