# cordova.js is missing on a new project

Tags: cordova

I have a brand new install of cordova3.1.0-0.1.0. I create a project like this `cordova create project com.example.project Project`. The project is created under the project/www but the file `cordova.js is missing`.

I'm working on windows XP, node 0.10.20 and npm 1.3.11.

Did I missing something?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

No, you're all good. Cordova.js will be generated when you build a specific platform (i.e. `cordova build android`). So it will be in your project/platforms/android/assets/www/ folder but not your project/www/ folder.

Comment: can you explain why they made it that way?!

Comment: @IbrahimHero Because each JS file is tailored to each platform. It's easier for you to only reference one file than having to sniff the OS yourself.

Comment: ibrahimHero, is there any harm in adding an empty cordova.js file in there during the development? ( I'm planning and launching the final app also as a web app, and this trick also helps with the 404 issue. )

Comment: I want to ship my app to Android, iOS and any browser. How can I add `cordova.js` for the browser so that I have things like `deviceready` events, and access to the plugins?

Answer (score 0):

I had to change my build target from the default `Android (Active)` to just plain `Android` from the dropdown menu and then it generated the file and built fine.  It seems like an initialization issue with Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score -5):

Try to `cd` into the dir and build the web version:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

Comment: This is definitelly not what the OP is asking about