# Karma-Jasmine testing Ionic Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined

Tags: javascript, cordova, karma-jasmine

I am trying to run Karma + Jasmine unit tests on a pre-existing project that's new to me..  coming up now on an error

`Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined`

What worries me is the following in `app.js`, any ideas are appreciated.  My guess is, this is generating the `cordova.js` on the fly.. (My question to the team will be, why?)

```
var myAppVar = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic', 'ngStorage', 'LocalStorageModule', 'blockUI', 'ngIdle', 'ngAnimate',
'angularCharts', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngDropdowns', 'ngSanitize'])
.run(myAppVarRun)
.config(MyAppRunConfig);

$(document).ready(function () {
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(Android)/)) {
    var cordovaScript = document.createElement('script');
    cordovaScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    cordovaScript.src = 'js/cordova.js';
    $("body").append(cordovaScript);

    if(window.screen.height <= 550) {
        console.log('using small screen Android');
        $("body").addClass('platform-android-small');
    }

} else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone)/)) {
    var cordovaScript = document.createElement('script');
    cordovaScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    cordovaScript.src = 'js/cordova.js';
    $("body").append(cordovaScript);

    if (window.screen.height == (960 / 2)) {
        console.log("using iPhone4/iPhone4s");
        $("body").addClass('platform-iphone-4');
    }

    if (!ionic.Platform.isIPad() && ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
        console.log('using iphone');
        $("body").addClass('platform-iphone');
    }
  }
});
```

Update : added the `cordova-ng.js` into `karma.conf.js` and get the same error.

`Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined` coming from the following file `./www/js/plugins/com.danielcwilson.plugins.analytics.UniversalAnalyticsPlugin/www/analytics.js`

Karma.conf.js

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
    'www/lib/js/ionic.bundle.js',
    'www/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js',
    'www/lib/ng-cordova/dist/ng-cordova.js',
    'www/js/**/*.js',
    'www/test/jasmine/*.js'
],
```

Comment: where do you have the Cordova file ?

Comment: `ng-cordova.js` doesn't exist in the project .. so as of now nowhere

Comment: you need to include it, Erik.

Comment: After including it, you need to add the module to the dependencies.

Comment: I wonder how the project was building without it.. Perhaps maven pulls it in

Comment: maven ? did you add the file and is it working now ?

Comment: In progress..  By the way this team uses maven instead of grunt to build ionic+Cordova+etc...

Comment: Let me know if its works. Just an advice: use gulp or grunt. Make sure you add the file and put it in the proper path. Are you using bower ?

Comment: We are not using bower, or gulp / grunt.. seems this team favors maven to build everything.. I added the files and added them to `karm.conf.js`, unfortunately it says the same error. I'll update

Comment: did you add the ngCordova to your dependencies ?

Comment: yes, see update.. worried the file wont exist until i build .. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19247356/cordova-js-is-missing-on-a-new-project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78362/discussion-between-nietzscheprogrammer-and-erik).