# Phonegap (Desktop Version) - 500 internal server error on cordova.js

Tags: cordova, mobile, phonegap-desktop-app

I'm starting my project `phonegap`. I haven't made changes yet, but it sends the following error in console log:

```
NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://192.168.0.103:3000/cordova.js
```

See image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRGSq.png

- Why does this error happen?
- Does it affect the operation of the Phonegap?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19247356/cordova-js-is-missing-on-a-new-project I've had the same issue. It seems when it's compiled it won't be a problem.