# Cordova: cordova.js is missing on a new project. My IDE is mad

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile-development

Please see the Q&A: [cordova.js is missing on a new project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19247356/cordova-js-is-missing-on-a-new-project)

My question is:  If I create a dummy cordova.js to make my IDE happy, -will it simply be overwritten or will it cause errors for the various platform compilers?

Comment: have you created apk and check, it should be there just refer it properly.

Comment: I haven't checked this, maybe I should test it myself.